# PSQL "BEGIN TRANSACTION" statement error

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, psql

I'm trying to run the following query in PSQL -

```
DO $$
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  LOCK TABLE tags IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM tags
     WHERE user_id = 1) > 3
  THEN
    INSERT INTO "tags" ("user_id", "friend_id", "status", "explanation", "score", "created_at", "updated_at")
    VALUES (1, 4, 'pending', '', 0.0, '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313', '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313')
    RETURNING "id";

    INSERT INTO "tags" ("user_id", "friend_id", "status", "explanation", "score", "created_at", "updated_at")
    VALUES (4, 1, 'pending', '', 0.0, '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313', '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313')
    RETURNING "id";
  ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
  END IF;

  COMMIT;
$$;
```

Unfortunately it keeps erroring out with -

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TRANSACTION"
LINE 2:   BEGIN TRANSACTION
                ^
```

and I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't like `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. I tried playing around with adding a `;` and removing the keyword `TRANSACTION` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an anonymous code block `BEGIN` signals the beginning of the code, not the SQL command `BEGIN`. Note that a function, including an anonymous code block, runs in its own transaction so you usually do not need an explicit additional transaction.

In your code a transaction is not needed at all since you are only `SELECT`ing data prior to the `ROLLBACK`. This should work just fine:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  cnt integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt
  FROM tags
  WHERE user_id = 1;
  IF cnt > 3 THEN
    INSERT INTO "tags" ("user_id", "friend_id", "status", "explanation", "score", "created_at", "updated_at")
    VALUES (1, 4, 'pending', '', 0.0, '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313', '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313');

    INSERT INTO "tags" ("user_id", "friend_id", "status", "explanation", "score", "created_at", "updated_at")
    VALUES (4, 1, 'pending', '', 0.0, '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313', '2016-02-29 00:43:58.969313');
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You are typically better off leaving concurrency resolution to the DBMS. Using an `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` on a table that is often accessed will slow the whole system down. If you are using PG 9.5, have a look at `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO`. In all versions you can also use less drastic locking strategies such as `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` (which is already very strict without locking the entire table) or advisory locks (much less invasive). Also note that concurrency conflicts do not occur when inserting records with keys that are guaranteed to be unique, such as those generated by a sequence.

Comment: Thanks. The background for this is that there are dozens of parallel processes running this simultaneously. The `LOCK TABLES` is a critical part of this so that each process briefly locks the table while it's performing it's `INSERT` operations, which ultimately prevents double-writing. Based on that, could I still insert the `LOCK TABLE matches IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;`? I don't imagine it locks the table by default